# Проблема с обновлением при переустановке Kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

После переустановки, при обновлении системы kali linux начали вылизать странные ошибки

[image: dpkg warning]

И там таких еще много вылезало. Уже раз восемь переустанавливал и все равно одно и тоже. Даже новый дистрибутив скачал, не помогло. А все установки заканчиваются так

[image: ошибка в конце]

А после перезагрузки, после очередной переустановки, с вероятностью 50% отваливается GraphCPU. Все происходит на VirtualBOX. Кто может подсказать в чем проблема и как ее решить? Буду весьма признателен